# Verificar se o intervalo de datas entre dois input's é menor que um mês e aplicar uma condição

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Tenho dois input's um para data inicial e outro para data final, preciso criar uma condição em `javascript`(jquery) para caso o intervalo for menor que um mês, exemplo: Vou desabilitar um botão caso o intervalo for menor que 1 mês.

Segue meu código atual:
[Aqui.](https://codepen.io/erickcouto/pen/VpNEjm)

Obs.: Não consegui fazer funcionar o código direto aqui no post, se alguem conseguir editar agradeço.

**UPDATE**
Consegui usando a dica do amigo abaixo, so fiz uns ajustes para se enquadrar no minha necessidade [Aqui](https://codepen.io/erickcouto/pen/VpNEjm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript**

```js
function Testar() {
var data_inicial = document.getElementById("dataInicial").value;
var data_final = document.getElementById("dataFinal").value;

var date1 = new Date(data_inicial);
var date2 = new Date(data_final);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
 if(diffDays <= 30)
 {
 alert("Menor que 30 dias - botão 'Testar' vai ser desabilitado");
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
 }
};
```

```html
  <label class="fa fa-calendar">
        <input id="dataInicial" name="dataInicial" type="text" value="">
  </label>
  <label class="fa fa-calendar">
        <input id="dataFinal" name="dataFinal" type="text" value="">
  </label>
  <div id="demo"><input name='Salvar' type='submit' id='Salvar' value='Testar' onclick='Testar()'></div>
```

**OBS; datas no formato mm/dd/aaaa**

Comment: Consegui fazer usando seu código, https://codepen.io/erickcouto/pen/VpNEjm.  Mto obrigado.

Comment: cara tudo bem, sei que ja me ajudou, tentei chegar ao resultado que eu gostaria mas tem algo errado ainda não ta 100% http://codepen.io/erickcouto/pen/VpNEjm  o que eu quero é quando selecionar uma data menor que 30 dias o botão por mês seja desativado e quando for maior q 30 ele seja ativado novamente, porem quando ele for desativado o grafico que aparece tem q ser o `por dia`.

Answer (score 0):

Amigão, rápido script, acho que se enquadra ao que precisa:

https://jsfiddle.net/sNniffer/7z0dfqj1/

Answer (score 0):

Este pequeno script vai retornar a diferença em **DIAS** das suas duas datas.

```
var dataIni = new Date($('#startDate').val());
var dataFim = new Date($('#endDate').val());
var diferencaEmMili = Math.abs(dataFim.getTime() - dataIni.getTime());
var diferencaEmDias = Math.ceil(diferencaEmMili / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Coloquei um exemplo aqui no JSFiddle com seu código, funcionando a comparação de datas

https://jsfiddle.net/kk7peacz/1/